# CSS sprite menu not show correct background

Tags: css, menu, background-image

I am new to CSS sprite menus so please bear with me (yes I've looked everywhere for the answer). I'm working on a small/simple mobile site. I have my main menu all worked out on the index page. Now I am on the first of the sub-pages. I just want a "Home" and a "Back" button. My problem is I selected the new sprite background, but it still wants to use the other one from the index page (specifically the "Home" button). What am I doing wrong. I know it is simple, but I am out of ideas. Here is my code:

```css
<style type="text/css">
ul {
 position: relative;
 width: 148px;
 height: 44px;
}
li {
 display: block;
 
}
li.subhome  a {
 background-image: url(css/sub-menu.jpg);
 display: block;
 width: 148px;
 height: 44px;
 background-repeat: no-repeat;
 float: left;
}
li.back  a {
 background-image: url(css/sub-menu.jpg);
 display: block;
 width: 148px;
 height: 44px;
 background-repeat: no-repeat;
 float: right;
}
</style>
```

```html
<body>
<div class="gridContainer clearfix">
  <div id="header" class="fluid "><img src="m_images/topbanner-logo.png" alt="" width="230" height="77" id="tcdfLogo"/></div>
  <nav class="fluid">
      <ul class="submenu">
      <li><a href="#" class="subhome">Home</a></li>
      <li><a href="#" class="back">Back</a></li>
      
    </ul>
</nav>
  <div id="mainContent" class="fluid ">
    <p><span class="headings">WELCOME TO TCDF MOBILE</span><br>
      We strive to get the best information to you about Tishomingo County and it's advantages. If you would like to get more detailed information, please visit us at our <a href="http://www.tishomingo.org" title="TCDF Full Website">full site</a>.</p>
  </div>
</div>
</div>
</body>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You added your class names on the `<a>` element thus you are targetting on the `<li>` in your CSS.

Change either your css selectors or move your class name on the `<li>` elements.

```
li  a.subhome {
    background-image: url(css/sub-menu.jpg);
    display: block;
    width: 148px;
    height: 44px;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    float: left;
}

li  a.back {
    background-image: url(css/sub-menu.jpg);
    display: block;
    width: 148px;
    height: 44px;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    float: right;
}
```

Comment: Thank you both! Sheesh, even "I" should have known I had my selector in the wrong place. Guess I'd been looking at it too long. With some more bg.pos. tweaking, all is fixed for now, but I'm sure I'll be back. Thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

Since you're using one sprite for both images you need to specify which part of the image that should be shown. This is done with the `background-position` property.

For example `background-position: -32px -12px;`. You'll need to play around with the values to find the correct image part since it depends on how your sprite look.

[**See CSS Image Sprites on MDN.**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/CSS/CSS_Image_Sprites)